# NCryptOpenStorageProvider returns 0x800706D9

Tags: winapi, cryptography, cng

The call `NCryptOpenStorageProvider(myProvider, MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER, 0)` returns 0x800706D9. Since I couldn't find this retcode in MSDN, I am really in a mess. What went wrong?

Comment: The `FormatMessage` Windows API function tells me that code means "There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper", which doesn't help much, but you might want to search for that message on the web and see if you find anything relevant. If you can provide a full example program which can reproduce the error someone might be able to figure it out, but if a trivial program just attempting to open the Microsoft Key Storage Provider is failing then there is probably something badly broken on your system.

Comment: Can you provide the snippet of code

Comment: I ran all Windows's services and everything is ok. Thanks.